# Grouping of sections in SWIFTUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting data from my database in firebase, data model is like this:

```
var label: String
var date: Double
var description: String
var categoryId: String
var ownerId: String
var patientId: String
var motconsuId: String
```

When receiving data, I want to collect them in a section by the categoryId field. But I can't do it, for some reason they are not grouped and duplicated.

[The result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPq8g.png)

My code which I display the view:

```
List {
        
        ForEach(self.motconsuLoadService.motconsu, id:\.categoryId) {
            (category) in
            
            Section(header: Text(category.categoryId)) {
                
                ForEach(self.motconsuLoadService.motconsu, id:\.motconsuId) {
                    (motconsu) in
                    MotconsuCard(motconsu: motconsu)
                }
            }
        }
    }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    .onAppear {
        self.motconsuLoadService.loadPatientsMotconsu(patientId: settings.defaultPatient)
    }
```

MotconsuCard:

```
    @ObservedObject var patientServices = PatientService()
var motconsu: MotconsuModel

var body: some View {
    
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(motconsu.label)
                .font(.system(size: 17))
            Text("\(motconsu.date)")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .padding(.top, 2)
        }
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, what is my mistake?

***EDIT:***
Made it easier, where the key is the category:

var groupByCategory: [(key: String, value: [MotconsuModel])] {

```
return Dictionary(grouping: vm.motconsus, by: { $0.categoryId }).sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key } )
```

}

Comment: The image you have linked to doesn’t say much, could you add some sample data as text perhaps but more importantly you should add the definition of motconsuLoadService.motconsu to the question

Answer (score 0):

You should gave correct property instead of **???** use something deferent than `motconsu`, The **???** must be connected to array of `category`

```
List {
    
    ForEach(self.motconsuLoadService.???, id:\.categoryId) {    // <<: Here 
        (category) in
        
        Section(header: Text(category.categoryId)) {
            
            ForEach(self.motconsuLoadService.motconsu, id:\.motconsuId) {
                (motconsu) in
                MotconsuCard(motconsu: motconsu)
            }
        }
    }
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
.onAppear {
    self.motconsuLoadService.loadPatientsMotconsu(patientId: settings.defaultPatient)
}
```